# Syntax for input redirection in IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

I need to enter the contents of a text (.txt) file as input for a Python (.py) file. Assuming the name of the text file is TextFile and the name of the Python file PythonFile, then the code should be as follows:

```
python PythonFile.py < TextFile.txt
```

Yet, when I try to do this in IDLE and type in

```
import PythonFile < TextFile,
```

IDLE gives me an invalid syntax message, pointing to the `<` sign. I tried all sorts of variations on this theme (i.e.,using or not using the file name extensions), but still got the same invalid-syntax message. How is the syntax different for input redirection in IDLE?

Comment: IDLE is not a shell; you can't do redirection like that at the Python prompt.

Comment: You cant do that in idle, for the `import`, it imports the functions from the module file, you cannot provide an argument? I still dont understand what your trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to run a script entering the input from a text document (rather than typing it in manually). So, it is not possible to do this in IDLE at all? Just now I tried doing this from the command prompt and it worked, but only after I specified the full paths to both files (i.e., not just the file names).

Answer (score 1):

If it works in the command line, then why do you want to do this in IDLE?  There are ways to achieve a similar result using, for example, `subprocess`, but a better way would be to refactor `PythonFile.py` so that you can call a function from it, e.g.:

```
>>> import PythonFile
>>> PythonFile.run_with_input('TextFile.txt')
```

If you post the contents of `PythonFile.py`, we might be able to help you do this.